# C# Winform - Smiley box like messenger

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I want to make i smiley box like live messenger.

[image: Smiley box]

How can i do that? I want to get the selected picture?

Thanks?

Comment: I think you have to define a new Form for this with a PictureBox Grid on it and an "ImageSelected" event.

Comment: if i do with new form how can i show it on the main button?

Comment: A ListView with View = Tile is close.  You'll need OwnerDraw to get it exactly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [ToolStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63k0z90h%28v=vs.80%29) and a [ToolStripSplitButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton.aspx) control and then I'd create my own control inhrited form a panel to show the smiles contained in a picturebox when will happen the click on the ToolStripSplitButton.

I tried to simulate the behaviour you would like to do. So here is some code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SuspendLayout();

        List<Bitmap> Smiles = new List<Bitmap>(); //Add images

        ToolStripSplitButton _toolStripSplitButton = new ToolStripSplitButton();
        _toolStripSplitButton.Size = new Size(23, 23);
        //_toolStripSplitButton.Image = myImage; //Add the image of the stripSplitButton

        ToolStrip _toolStrip = new ToolStrip();
        _toolStrip.Size = new Size(ClientSize.Width, 10);
        _toolStrip.Location = new Point(0, this.ClientSize.Height - _toolStrip.Height);
        _toolStrip.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        _toolStrip.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        _toolStrip.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { _toolStripSplitButton });

        SmileBox smilebox = new SmileBox(new Point(_toolStripSplitButton.Bounds.Location.X, _toolStrip.Location.Y - 18), 6);
        smilebox.Visible = false;

        Controls.Add(smilebox);

        foreach (Bitmap bmp in Smiles)
            smilebox.AddItem(bmp);

        _toolStripSplitButton.Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            smilebox.Visible = true;
        });

        Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            smilebox.Visible = false;
        });

        this.Controls.Add(_toolStrip);
        this.ResumeLayout();
    }

    void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class SmileBox : Panel
{
    public List<Item> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    Size _ItemSpace = new Size(20, 20);
    Point _ItemLocation;
    int _rowelements = 0;

    public SmileBox(Point Location, int RowElements)
    {
        BackColor = Color.LightGray;

        Height = _ItemSpace.Height;
        Width = _ItemSpace.Width * RowElements;

        this.Location = new Point(Location.X, Location.Y - Height);
        _ItemLocation = new Point(0, 0);
        _rowelements = RowElements;
    }

    int count = 1;
    public void AddItem(Bitmap Image)
    {
        Item item = new Item(_ItemSpace, _ItemLocation, Image);

        if (_ItemLocation.X + _ItemSpace.Width >= Width)
            _ItemLocation = new Point(0, _ItemLocation.Y);
        else
            _ItemLocation = new Point(_ItemLocation.X + _ItemSpace.Width, _ItemLocation.Y);

        if (count == _rowelements)
        {
            _ItemLocation = new Point(_ItemLocation.X, _ItemLocation.Y + _ItemSpace.Height);
            Height += _ItemSpace.Height;
            Location = new Point(Location.X, Location.Y - _ItemSpace.Height);

            count = 0;
        }

        count++;

        Controls.Add(item);
    }
}

class Item : PictureBox
{
    int _BorderSpace = 2;

    public Item(Size Size, Point Location, Bitmap Image)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(Size.Width - 2 * _BorderSpace, Size.Height - 2 * _BorderSpace);
        this.Location = new Point(Location.X + _BorderSpace, Location.Y + _BorderSpace);
        this.Image = new Bitmap(Image, this.ClientSize);

        Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Here what do you want to do when the user click on the smile
        });

        MouseEnter += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Focus();
            Invalidate();
        });
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Focus();
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnLeave(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);

        if (this.Focused)
        {
            ClientRectangle.Inflate(-1, -1);
            Rectangle rect = ClientRectangle;
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(pe.Graphics, rect);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a snapshot of what create this code:

[image]

And when you are over a smile:

[image]

And here you can click on single item.

Comment: when i click it, smile box doesnt open?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my code... Now it should work.

Comment: sorry but it doesnt still work

Comment: Yeah, I've solved some problems, but now there is another one that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Ok I've edited my code and I tested it, It seem to work very well. :)

Comment: i cant resize form with this? how can we correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a user control or a new form (if you want a floating thing), with picture boxes for each smilies. Whenever a user clicks on a picture box (Click event) you can register the click and paste the smiley to the appropriate location.

Actually, you can create a new picture box class that inherits everything from the built-in one, and you add one public string, which contains the smiley's code. You get the sender object in the event, so all you have to do is to read that string in the Click event's function.